# What is the potential difference between two points?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, potential

[image]

I need to find the potential difference between A and D points. I wrote the following : 
$$\frac{φ_B - φ_A}{2}=\frac{φ_A-φ_E}{6}$$

because current between B and A equals to current between A and E. Also I wrote above formula for the second one: 
$$\frac{φ_C - φ_D}{9}=\frac{φ_D-φ_F}{3}$$

We know that $$φ_B=φ_C$$ $$ φ_E=φ_F$$

But anyway I've got two equations with 4 unknown variables. So , is there any idea?

Comment: You haven't used all the information available: the total current is equal to the sum of the currents in the branches, and $V_{BE} = V_{CF} = 18V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To total resistance of the circuit is $$ \frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R_B+R_E}+\frac{1}{R_C+R_F}$$ Then
\begin{align}
&\Delta V=RI &I=I_1+I_2 \\
&\Delta V=(R_B+R_E)I_1  &\Delta V=(R_C+R_F)I_2 
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
&\Delta V_{BA}=R_B I_1 &\Delta V_{CD}=R_C I_2 
\end{align}

So

$$ \Delta V-\Delta V_{BA}-\Delta V+\Delta V_{CD}=\Delta V_{CD}-\Delta V_{BA}=\Delta V_{AD}$$

Answer (score 0):

Both sets of resistors form voltage dividers.

$$V_1 = V_A - V_D$$
$$V_1 = \frac {6k\Omega}{6k\Omega+ 2k\Omega}\times 18V - \frac {3k\Omega}{3k\Omega+ 9k\Omega}\times 18V$$